# is equals() supposed to be recursive/deep?

Tags: java, equals

None really talks about this aspect of *equals()* and *hasCode()*, but there is potentially massive impact on *equals()* and *hashCode()* behavior. Massive when dealing with a bit more complex objects referencing other objects.

Joshua Bloch in his Effective Java does not even mention it in his "overriding equals() method" chapter. All his examples are trivialities like Point and ColorPoint, all with just primitive or nearly primitive types.

Can recursivity be avoided? Sometimes hardly. Assume:

```
Person {
    String name;
    Address address;
}
```

Both fields has to go to **business key** (as Hibernate guys call it), they are both **value components** (as Joshua Bloch has it). And Address is a complex object itself. Recursion.

Be aware, IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ does generates recursive equals() and hashCode().
They by default use all fields. If you apply generator tools an mass, you asking for troubles.

One trouble is you can get a **StackOverflowError**. Here my [simple test proving it](https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/a-java-core-playground/src/7ae6bfb937a2a5270331dad7db617bc6be57888d/src/my/code/a001/equality/B1EqualsWithHiddenInfiniteLoopTest.java?at=master).
All is needed is class having as a "value component" another object, forming a object graph and recommended equals() implementation. Yes, you need a graph in that cycle, but that is nothing unrealistic (imagine molecules, paths on map, interlinked transactions..).

Another trouble is **performance**. What is recommended for equals() is in fact comparing of two object graphs, potentially huge graphs, one can end up comparing thousands of nodes without knowing it. And not all of them are necessary in the memory! Consider that some objects may be lazy loadable. One can end up loading half of the database on one equals() or hashCode() call.

Paradox is, the more rigorously you override equals() and hashCode() as you are encouraged to do, the more likely you get into troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the equals() method should test logical equality. In some cases, that may descend more deeply than the physical object, and in others, it may not.

If testing logical equality is not feasible, due to performance or other concerns, then you can leave the default implementation provided by Object, and not rely on equals(). For example, you don't have to use your object graph as a key in a collection.

Bloch does say this:

> The easiest way to avoid problems is not to override the equals method, in which case each instance of the class is equal only to itself.

Comment: So how do you prevent for example StackOverflowError? I can think of identity cache, checking if the object was already descended. But this would makes equals really complex method (plus additional issues like preventing concurrent access to the cache, etc..)

Comment: If the objects have a parent-child relationship, don't include the parent in the equality test. If the objects are in an arbitrary graph, then don't traverse over the same object more than once during the equality test (an auxiliary equality test may be useful for this).

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two logical questions, which would be meaningful for any two references of any type, which it would at various times be useful for `equals` to test:

1. Can the type promise that the two references will forevermore identify equivalent objects?
2. Can the type promise that the two references will identify equivalent objects as long as the code which holds the references neither modifies the objects, nor exposes them to code that will?

If a reference identifies an object that might change at any time without notice, the only references that should be considered equivalent are those which identify the same object.  If a reference identifies an object of a deeply-immutable type, and is never used in ways that test its identity (e.g. locking, `IdentityHashSet`, etc.) then all references to objects holding equal content should be considered equivalent.  In both of the above situations, the proper behavior of `equals` is clear and unambiguous, since in the former case the proper answer for both questions would be obtained by testing reference identity, and in the latter case the proper answer would be obtained by testing deep equality.

Unfortunately, there's a very common scenario where the answers to the two questions diverge: when the only extant references to objects of mutable type are held by code which knows that no references to those objects will ever be held by code that might mutate them nor test them for reference identity.  In that scenario, if two such objects presently encapsulate the same state, they will forever more do so, and thus equivalence should be based upon equivalence of constituents rather than upon reference identity.  In other words, `equals` should be based upon how nested objects answer the second question.

Because the meaning of equality depends upon information which is only known by the holder of a reference, and not by the object identified by the reference, it's not really possible for an `equals` method to know what style of equality is appropriate.  Types that know that the things to which they hold references might spontaneously change should test reference equality of those constituent parts, while types that know they won't change should generally test deep equality.  Things like collections should allow the owner to specify whether the things stored in the collections could spontaneously change, and test equality on that basis; unfortunately, relatively few of the built-in collections include any such facility (code can select between e.g. `HashTable` and `IdentityHashTable` to distinguish what kind of test is appropriate for keys, but most kinds of collections have no equivalent choice).  The best one can do is probably have each new collection type offer in its constructor a choice of encapsulation mode: regard the collection itself as something that might be changed without notice (report reference equality on the collection), assume the collection will hold an unchanging set of references to things that might change without notice (test reference equality on the contents), assume that neither the collection nor the constituent objects will change (test `equals` of each constituent object), or--for collections of arrays or of nested collections that don't support deep-equality testing--perform super-deep equality testing to a specified depth.